# Missing 1 required positional argument board game

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface

I am trying to create the GUI code for my connect four boardgame but error's keep on coming up that I don't know how to correct. Can anyone help? The error:
TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'buttns_list'

Code:

```
def __init__(self):


    self.mw = tkinter.Tk()
    self.mw.title = ("Connect Four")

    self.rows = 6
    self.cols = 7
    self.buttons_2d_list = []
    for i in range (self.rows):
        self.rows = ['']*self.cols
        self.buttons_2d_list.append(self.rows)

    self.gboard = ConnectFourBoard()
    p1 = HumanPlayer("X")
    p2 = ComputerPlayer("O", self.buttns_list)

    self.players_1st = (p1, p2)
    self.currnt_player_index = 0
    self.winner = False

def clicked_btn(self, x, y):

    p = self.players_1st[self.currnt_player_index]

    button = self.buttons_2d_list[x][y]
    if button["text"] == "":
        button["text"] = p.get_player_symbol()

        self.gboard.MakeMove(x, y, p.get_player_symbol())

        winner = self.gboard.CheckForWin()

        is_full = self.gboard.FullBoard()

        if winner == True:

            win_message = ("Player %s is the winner!" %p.get_player_symbol())
            messagebox.showinfo("Winner Info", win_messge)
            self.mw.destroy()
            exit()

        elif is_full == True:
            messagebox.showinfo("Winner Info", "The game is a draw")
            self.mw.destroy()
            exit()
        else:
            pass

        if self.currnt_player_index == 1:
            self.currnt_player_index = 0
        else:
            self.currnt_player_index += 1

        p = self.players_1st[self.currnt_player_index]
        p.play()



import random
```

class ComputerPlayer(Player):

```
def __init__(self, letter, buttns_list):
    Player.__init__(self, letter)
    self.buttons_2d_list = buttns_list

def play(self):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me from the rest of the code exactly what you should be passing here, but your **init** calls for a letter, which you do have, and a buttns_list, which you don't:

```
def __init__(self, letter, buttns_list):
```

So the error comes from this line:

`p2 = ComputerPlayer("O")`

Either:

1) Pass in a buttns_list if your ComputerPlayer class needs it

```
p2 = ComputerPlayer("O", self.buttons_2d_list)` # in GameGUI init
```

2) Get rid of it if this was added by mistake:

```
class ComputerPlayer(Player):

    def __init__(self, letter):
        Player.__init__(self, letter)
```

Comment: I added the self.buttns_list into ComputerPlayer however, this error comes up: AttributeError: 'GameGUI' object has no attribute 'buttns_list'
I'm trying to create the board and buttons for my boardgame

Comment: @sarb Could you refresh your current code and could and it sounds like you try to pass `self.buttns_list` during `GamerGUI`, but `self` is referring to `GamerGUI` at the given moment, thus trying to pass `GamerGUI.buttns_list` what does not exist.

Comment: I've updated my current code, what should I do then?

Comment: Hi @sarb, I had a small typo which I've fixed in item #1. Keep in mind this is just an example. I'm just showing you how to pass in a variable when the ComputerPlayer is created.